# Making system wide equalizer in OSX with AU Lab, but I'm getting an annoying noise. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: macos, audio, equalizer

Using [this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/18/equalizer-for-all-audio-mac-os-x/) I'm trying to make a system wide equalizer in Mavericks. But unfortunately when I set up the new document in AU Lab and run the audio engine. I get [this annoying constant noise](http://devign.nl/AU-Lab-noise.mp3) unless I lower my volume to about 50%. Is there a way to get rid of that noise without having to lower my volume? For example, is there a noise removal filter in that app? I couldn't find it.